# Notches on tags not appearing on 'Top Tags' section of profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, user-profile

As you can see, the notches/knobs/things on the tags in the 'Top Tags' section of the user profile are not displaying:

[image]

It does seem to display on the top tag though.

---

*As a side note, long tags seem to be shortened rather then displaying their full name. Is this a bug or a feature?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (or [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)?) - Arqade no longer has tags that look like the bullets in the question's screenshot, so the formatting of tags in the 'Top Tags' place is now consistent:

[image: Top Tags Section with new tags]

This happened as part of the Stack Exchange Network-wide [standardised site design rollout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/179041):

> ...there are several things that will now be standardized to follow the look and feel on Stack Overflow...
>
> Standardized items will include:
>
> - Navigation
> - Fonts
> - Buttons/Icons
> - Tags
> - Newsletter ads

Arqade's site design rollout was announced/discussed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182).